# ls cannot display utf8 encoded file name correctly when ssh-ing to an OS X machine

Tags: ssh, macos, putty, utf-8

The problem I'm trying to resolve here is that, in the terminal of an ssh session to an OS X machine, the output of the `ls` command cannot display utf8 encoded Chinese characters in file names correctly (showing something like `???`).  The ssh client I'm using is `securecrt` and `putty` on Windows (both are configured to use utf8 encoding).  Both of them have this problem.  On the other hand, utf8 characters in file contents can be displayed correctly (as via `vim` and `cat`), and the auto complete feature of bash can also display utf8 characters in file names correctly (both in the candidates list when there are multiple candidates, and in the file name that gets auto completed when there is only one candidate.)

So the question is, how to make `ls` correctly display utf8 encoded file names in the terminal of an ssh session to an OS X machine?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually caused due to environmental variables, so please check it first.
type `env` you can get the result. In my case set LANG(`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`) just work.

Answer (score 0):

For Putty: On the OSX target machine, lookup the LC_CTYPE environment variable (`echo $LC_CTYPE`). It should be *UTF-8* or something like *en_EN.UTF-8*. (If it's only something like "en_EN" then it's set to ISO. In this case change it to *en_EN.UTF-8* by adding `export LC_CTYPE=en_EN.UTF-8` to your *$HOME/.bash_profile*). On your windows machine in Putty go to the configuriation -> window/translatation and there select the same character set as the env var on your OSX machine. If both the env var on the server and the putty settings are the same, it should be working.